# Hide git submodule changes from version control window

Tags: git, android-studio, git-submodules, android-studio-3.0

I'm working on git project with submodules. When I pull changes from remote repository my default change list contains changed *submodule meta files*:

[image: meta files]

And I need to move *this files* to another change list:

[image: meta files in Git change list]

How I can avoid this <strike>pain</strike> useless work?

Comment: Have you added .gitignore to your project?

Comment: @Al-Amin it is not files on the screen. It's git submodules inside of "main project" directory and I need to work with sources of submodules too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android Studio 3.5 Canary 8 *submodule meta files* are not moving to *Default Changelist* after pull command. All you need move it to *Git* changelist (look at description of question) and forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

[Android Studio 3.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#3-0-0) (Oct. 2017) is based on [IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+2017.1.2+Release+Notes).
Even the latest [Android Studio 3.2](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#3-2-0) (Sept. 2018) is only based on [July 2018 IntelliJ 2018.1.6](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/07/intellij-idea-2018-1-6-is-released/)

And Git submodules support only fully supported in [2018.3 (Nov. 2018)](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/11/intellij-idea-2018-3-github-pull-requests-java-12-multiline-todo-comments-git-submodule-support-and-more/).
Even then, there are still pending bugs ([IDEA-100075](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100075), [IDEA-196506](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-196506) illustrated [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002018220-CLion-and-committing-with-git-submodules))

Check first if the latest IntelliJ 2018.3.1 if the GitHub pull request support would improve your workflow: that would mean a later Android Studio will eventually resolve your current issue.
[Since 2018.1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/02/intellij-idea-2018-1-eap-partial-git-commits-and-more/), the [local change tabs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/version-control-tool-window-local-changes-tab.html) allows to group by modules, which will simplify moving module changes to a new changeset.

[image: https://d3nmt5vlzunoa1.cloudfront.net/idea/files/2018/02/Screen-Shot-2018-02-15-at-18.39.32.png]

Comment: It's not solve my issue. It's just group changes by repositories and when I pull changes from remote I have same situation as in my question

Comment: @XIII-th That means, as I mention in the answer, that this issue is not yet resolved on IntelliJ IDEA side.

Answer (score -2):

Add files and folders which one you don't want to add to your repository.

Here is an example of .gitignore file -

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/libraries
/.idea/modules.xml
/.idea/workspace.xml
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
.externalNativeBuild
```

File location will be -

[image]

Comment: Git submodules it's not something to be ignored. It's a git repo linked to another git repo. It's not a good idea to use `.gitignore` in this case.